# Difference between tty group and dialout group

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, operating-system

While I am exploring Linux OS I face various issues one of which is - what is the difference between /dev/tty* and /dev/ttyS*, also why /dev/tty* are members of group tty and /dev/ttyS* of dialout.

Comment: Have you considered reading the documentation? `man 4 tty` `man 4 ttyS`